# Not able to set cookie from expressjs on android webview

Tags: android, node.js, express, cookies

For some weird reason I am not able to set the cookie from the backend(nodejs and expressjs) to the client(the android webview).

This is my nodejs code.

```
app.get('/setcookie',(req,res)=>{
  res.cookie('test','heeeee')
  res.send({"status":"You set the cookie!"})
})



app.get('/getcookie',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.cookies.test)
  res.send({"status":req.cookies.test})
})
```

This is my android studio code for the webview.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(myWebView.getContext());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.124:3000/test.html");
    }
}
```

Any ideas why im not able to set a cookie on the client(webview) from expressjs(nodejs)
Also, I tried this on the browser and it works flawlessly.